# Shading artifacts in Cycles with no apparent cause

Tags: shadows

Why is my shading producing artifacts? I've search around with no solution. I can get a smooth look in Solid view, but Cycles and Eevee create artifacts. the topography is clean, no ngons, subdivided.

Things I've tried:
-Recalculating normals
-checking for n-gons (there are none)

- Merge by distance to check for overlapping vertices (none)
- smoothing options in Mesh->Shading.

The only thing that has worked is subsurf modifier, but I don't want to use that.
The model was imported as an .obj, and I find that most imported .objs have similar problems.

What can I do to get a smoother look, like in solid view?

Thanks[image]